# Extracting part of a value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a dictionary that contains a gene sequence. The sequence data is stored as a value, with the name of the gene as a key. I.e.: HDC: AATGCAGACCTTACGTAA

Now I am supposed to assign variables to both the second and second to last nucleotide. 
I have done this as follows:

```
HDCList = dict['HDC']
start = HDCList[1]
stop = HDCList[16]
```

Not sure if copying the value as a list is necessary. 
Further, I am trying to then use these variables to extract everything in between (including the start and stop positions). I am not sure how to approach this. Ordinarily, I'd think that you could just slice the list, but considering that we must use the variables 'start' and 'stop' I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice a string like a list. Also you can use negative indexes that counts from the right:

```
>>> s = "AATGCAGACCTTACGTAA"
>>> s[1]
'A'
>>> s[-2]
'A'
>>> start = 1
>>> stop = -2
>>> s[start: stop+1]
'ATGCAGACCTTACGTA'
```

See more on slicing in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: For some reason when I try this, the output is blank, with no error message.